# vector, skewed data, when passing it to a function as pointer

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am having an interface that takes an integer pointer (I can't change this interface). I want to fill a `vector` in some other class and want to call that interface from the client code through my `class`. But when I retrieve values from `vector`, it always start from 0. I don't want to declare the `vector` as `static` and I can't pass `vector` by-value or by-reference. I can only pass the integer pointer.

I have written code for simulating this scenario.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//--Class SpMx; I can't change anything here--//
class SpMx{
public:
  void getVector(int* values_);
  void showValues();
private:
  int* values;
};

//--definition--//
void SpMx::getVector(int* values_) {
  values = values_;
}


void SpMx::showValues(){

  for(size_t i = 0; i< 13; ++i)

    std::cout<<values[i]<<std::endl;
}

//--class Mx; I can make change here--//
class Mx{

public:
  Mx() = default;
  SpMx* myFunc();
};

//--definition--//
SpMx* Mx::myFunc(){

  //hard coded for testing
  int ary[] = {2, 110, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 120, 140, 160};
  std::vector<int> myVector(ary, ary +sizeof(ary)/sizeof(int)); 
  SpMx* sMx_obj = new SpMx();
  sMx_obj->getVector(&myVector[0]);
  return sMx_obj;
}

//--main--//
int main(){
  Mx mx_obj;
  SpMx* spmx_obj;
  spmx_obj = mx_obj.myFunc();
  spmx_obj->showValues();
  delete spmx_obj;
  return 0;
}

//output 
0, 110, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 120, 140, 160
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SpMx initializer:

```
void SpMx::getVector(int* values_) {
  values = values_;
}
```

clearly expects a pointer to the beginning of an array which the SpMx will be allowed to keep (or at least which will have a lifetime as long as the SpMx). So declare it on the heap (and don't use the internal implementation of a `std::vector`, that's not for use by outsiders):

```
#include <algorithm>

SpMx* Mx::myFunc(){

  //hard coded for testing
  int ary[] = {2, 110, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 120, 140, 160};
  int *p = new int[14];
  std::copy(ary, ary+13, p);

  SpMx* sMx_obj = new SpMx();

  sMx_obj->getVector(p);
  return sMx_obj;
}
```

Don't forget to delete the array when the SpMx is done with it (e.g. in the SpMx destructor), or you'll get a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, copying array on heap would work but is there any other way then copying; and where "ary" being declared as local variable?

Comment: @Movis: Yes there is, but I don't know that you would like it any better. *Why* do you not want to use `copy` and a local variable?

Comment: I wanted to avoid new keyword(not using c++11, so can't use smart pointers) and in real code it is vector being filled not array, and that's why I mentioned "hard coded for testing".

Comment: @Movis: You can write your own loop for copying -- and your own smart pointer, if you want it. If by "new keyword" you mean a new keyword, I don't know which one you're referring to; if you mean the `new` keyword, I don't understand why-- unless you are trying to avoid dynamic memory entirely, which is almost impossible because of the implementation of `SpMx`.

Answer (score 1):

This function is going to cause you problems

```
SpMx* Mx::myFunc(){    
  int ary[] = {2, 110, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 120, 140, 160};
  std::vector<int> myVector(ary, ary +sizeof(ary)/sizeof(int)); 
  SpMx* sMx_obj = new SpMx();
  sMx_obj->getVector(&myVector[0]);
  return sMx_obj;
}
```

The vector `myVector` is declared within the scope of this function. You then have your `sMx_obj`'s `values` pointer pointing at this vectors memory. As soon as the vector falls out of scope, that memory is now garbage. But you return the `SpMx` object, with the pointer still pointing at that garbage.

You need to make sure that your `SpMx` object owns that memory, or at least the array it is pointing to lives as long as your `SpMx` object does.

Comment: Thanks Cory for your prompt reply. Yes, vector destructor called as soon as myVector goes out of scope.